# How to find the occurrence of a number in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a data set like this in Excel

[image]

I need an output that will give me the first Month in which my value exceeded 10.
For example in this case function should give me Month 5 as answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
=INDEX($B$1:$H$1,,MATCH(0,0/($B$2:$H$2>=10),0))
```

This is an array formula, so you will need to hit CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER

Comment: Anther variation that should work:

`=INDEX($A$1:$F$1,,MIN(IF(($A$2:$F$2>=10),COLUMN($A$2:$F$2))))`

This is also an array.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code below:

```
Range("B2").Select
Dim i As Integer
i=0
Do While ActiveCell.value <> ""
If ActiveCell.value > 10 Then
    Cells(4 + i, 2).value = ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).value
    i = i + 1
End If
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Activate
Loop
```

Couple of assumptions: Cell A1 contains "Month" and Cell A2 contains "Loan". Further the output you are expecting will be displayed from Cell B4 and printed downwards in the B column(B4, B5, B6 and so on).

Hope this helps!

Comment: My requirement is to do this using a function . :/

Comment: Can you please elaborate more on your requirement? What specifically do you mean when you say that you want it as a function? If you are meaning as a inbuilt excel function, then you can only work for a particular cell, but not the entire range. Please elaborate your need as it may help to think of a solution as per your need.

Comment: I want something like this =MATCH(G268,D74:BK74,0)

This function is doing my purpose but it is giving only first occurrence.

Comment: Don't tag your question as "excel-vba" next time, if you don't want the answer to be an VBA script.

Answer (score 0):

This solution is far from being clean and clever, but if you have 12 months, you can just use IF test nested 12 times. It goes like:

```
=IF($B2>10;$B$1;IF($C2>10;$C$1;IF($D2>10;$D$1;
IF($E2>10;$E$1;IF($F2>10;$F$1;IF($G2>10;$G$1;
IF($H2>10;$H$1;IF($I2>10;$I$1;IF($J2>10;$J$1;
IF($K2>10;$K$1;IF($L2>10;$L$1;IF($M2>10;$M$1;"None"))))))))))))
```

And works for columns organized like:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking to create function? if not you can just do this.

[image]

The check is

> =IF(B3>10,TRUE)

You can hide the check if your excel is for reporting purpose